# Assume $\langle Su, u \rangle \ge 0$ for all $u \in H$. Is it true that $R(S) = R(S^*)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

[Exercise 5.20.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693119/brezis-exercise-5-20-1) in Brezis' *Functional Analysis* is stated as follows

> Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space. Let $S :H \to H$ be a bounded linear operator such that $\langle Su, u \rangle \ge 0$ for all $u \in H$. Let $N(S)$ be the kernel of $S$ and $R(S)$ the range of $S$. Then $N(S) = R(S)^\perp$.

At page 45 of the same book, we have

> **Corollary 2.18.** Let $E, F$ be Banach spaces. Let $A: D(A) \subset E \rightarrow F$ be an unbounded linear operator with $D(A)$ a vector subspace of $E$. Let $A$ be densely defined, i.e., $D(A)$ is dense in $E$. Let $A$ be closed, i.e., its graph is closed in $E \times F$. If $A^*: D(A^*) \subset F^* \rightarrow E^*$ is the adjoint operator of $A$, then
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> N(A) & =R\left(A^{*}\right)^{\perp}, \\
> N\left(A^{*}\right) & =R(A)^{\perp}, \\
> N(A)^{\perp} & \supset \overline{R\left(A^{*}\right)}, \\
> N\left(A^{*}\right)^{\perp} & =\overline{R(A)} .
> \end{aligned}
> $$

Let $S$ be the operator in **Exercise 5.20.1** and $S^*$ its adjoint. Then **Corollary 2.18.** implies that $N(S) = N(S^*)$ and $R(S)^\perp = R(S^*)^\perp$.

> 1. Is it true that $R(S) = R(S^*)$?
> 2. Is there a geometric meaning of the condition $\langle Su, u \rangle \ge 0 \quad \forall u \in H$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that $R(S)\ne R(S^*)$. Let $H=l^2$ and $T$ the right-shift operator. Then $T^*$ is the left-shift and $T^*T=I$. Define $S:=I-T$.
Then
$$
\langle Su,u\rangle = \langle (I-\frac12 T - \frac12 T^*)u,u\rangle
= \frac12 \langle (I-  T^*)(I- T)u,u\rangle
= \|(I-R)u\|^2.
$$
It is easy to check that $N(S)=N(S^*)=\{0\}$.

Let $e_1 = (1,0,\dots)$. Then $S^*e_1 = e_1$, but $e_1 \not\in  R(S)$.
If $Sv = e_1$ it follows inductively that $v=(1,1,\dots)$, which is not in $l^2$.

---

The claim $R(S)=R(S^*)$ is true if $R(S)$ (or equivalently $R(S^*)$) is closed.

---

The condition $\langle Su,u\rangle\ge0$ for all $u$ is equivalent to $\langle (S+S^*)u,u\rangle\ge0$, which means that the self-adjoint (or symmetric) part $\frac12(S+S^*)$ of $S$ is positive semidefinite.